# How to exclude by xpath certain keyword and ID

Tags: xpath

I have xml file, where I have many products. Not all of them I would like to use for import. By using XPATH I need to exclude from import every item, which contains specific name: lens

```
<items>
<item>

 <id>12612991</id>
 <name>Polarized Lens</name>
 <description></description>
 <video>link</video>
 <status>expired</status>
 <price>0</price>
 <currency></currency>

</item>

<item>

 <id>12612921</id>
 <name>Polarized glass</name>
 <description>asdf</description>
 <video>link</video>
 <status>expired</status>
 <price>0</price>
 <currency></currency>

</item>
</items>
```

I am trying to use this:

```
//*[not(contains(name(),'Lens'))]
```

So only one item from two will be imported, in this case -> `Polarized glass`

Also I am trying to exclude from import any items with specific ID`s

```
//*[not(contains(ID(),'12612921,12612926,12612924'))]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below XPath to get required output:

```
//item[not(contains(name/text(), 'Lens')) and not(id=('12612921', '12612926', '12612924'))]
```

If you use XPath 1.0:

```
//item[not(contains(name/text(), 'Lens')) and not(id='12612921') and not(id='12612926') and not(id='12612924')]
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot, Works like charm :)

Comment: Welcome. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Comment: One more Q about Xpath rule.

How to create this xpath usisng wp all import?

I have products categories in wordpress, and while importing I want to assign products to category. All by filtering or keyword in name: Lens from xml ... This item will be assigned to category Camera

Is it possible to do it or now?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no experience with *wp all import*. You can create new ticket regarding this issue

Comment: I will, I need to wait 90 minutes before new post. anyway this is not about wp all import, but only about rule which wp all import will process. Like your helped me before.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know about 90 minutes rule. Even if it's about XPath I still need XML sample and desired output to help you...

Comment: maybe only for new users. I will use new post in 30 minutes :) so you can reply. XML is the same.